# Type 'Observable<>' is missing properties in Angular Nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, http, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am facing this problem when it set my function as `getCalendarEvents(): Observable<Array<CalendarEvent>>{`. The error message shows like `Type 'Observable<CalendarEvent[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'CalendarEvent[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 24 more.`

This is the service.ts

```
getCalendarEvents(): Observable<Array<CalendarEvent>>{
         var listCal:any = []
         return this.getCalendarData().pipe(map((data: any) => {
          listCal = data;
        console.log('list cal', listCal)
             let startDate: Date,
             endDate: Date,
             event: CalendarEvent;
             let colors: Array<Color> = [new Color(200, 188, 26, 214), new Color(220, 255, 109, 130), new Color(255, 55, 45, 255), new Color(199, 17, 227, 10), new Color(255, 255, 54, 3)];
             let events: Array<CalendarEvent> = new Array<CalendarEvent>();
             for (let i = 1; i < listCal.length; i++) {
                  event = new CalendarEvent(listCal[i].title, new Date(listCal[i].date), new Date(listCal[i].date), false, colors[i * 10 % (listCal[i].colour.length - 1)]);    

                  events.push(event);     
              }
             return events;
            }));          
    }
```

In the service.ts, the error does not show but because of the declaration I am facing the above error in the calendar component which is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { calendarApiService } from './service/api.service';
import { CalendarClass } from './classes/calendarClass';
import { RadCalendar, CalendarEvent, CalendarSelectionEventData } from "nativescript-ui-calendar";

@Component({
  selector: 'ns-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.css'],
  moduleId: module.id,
  providers: [calendarApiService]
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _calendarApiService: calendarApiService) {
    //console.log("hi");

   }
   private _events: Array<CalendarEvent>;
   private _listItems: Array<CalendarEvent>;

   listOfCalendar: CalendarClass[];




get eventSource() {
    return this._events;
}

get myItems(): Array<CalendarEvent> {
    return this._listItems;
}

set myItems(value) {
    this._listItems = value;
}

// ngOnInit() {
//     this._events = this._calendarService.getCalendarEvents();
// }


ngOnInit() {

  this._events = this._calendarApiService.getCalendarEvents();


  this._calendarApiService.getCalendarData() 
  .subscribe( 
  (data:any)=>{ 
  this.listOfCalendar = data; 
  } 
  );

  //console.log(this.listOfCalendar);

}

onDateSelected(args: CalendarSelectionEventData) {
    const calendar: RadCalendar = args.object;
    const date: Date = args.date;
    const events: Array<CalendarEvent> = calendar.getEventsForDate(date);


    this.myItems = events;
}


}
```

Comment: can you create a playground if possible ? That would be easier to debug.

Comment: is it possible to create playground in stackoverflow? I did not get your question!
I am facing error in this line `this._events = this._calendarApiService.getCalendarEvents();`

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/ use that to show your code. you can run on any device with the NS preview app

Comment: When you choose the template and edit, it will show you save button. After saving you can see the change in URL and you can copy that e.g. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=cD3cYS

Comment: @NarendraMongiya Check now! https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=J5wVUR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189040/discussion-between-narendra-mongiya-and-nabid).

Comment: did you solved the issue? how? @Nabid

Comment: @calios answer is given below check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you should return `Array<CalendarEvent>` from your method or don't specity any type. As your trying to assign Array to `Observable<Array<CalendarEvent>`.

```
getCalendarEvents(){
         var listCal:any = []
         this.getCalendarData().pipe(map((data: any) => {
          listCal = data;
        console.log('list cal', listCal)
             let startDate: Date,
             endDate: Date,
             event: CalendarEvent;
             let colors: Array<Color> = [new Color(200, 188, 26, 214), new Color(220, 255, 109, 130), new Color(255, 55, 45, 255), new Color(199, 17, 227, 10), new Color(255, 255, 54, 3)];
             let events: Array<CalendarEvent> = new Array<CalendarEvent>();
             for (let i = 1; i < listCal.length; i++) {
                  event = new CalendarEvent(listCal[i].title, new Date(listCal[i].date), new Date(listCal[i].date), false, colors[i * 10 % (listCal[i].colour.length - 1)]);    

                  events.push(event);     
              }
             return events;
            }));          
    }
```

Comment: Its still giving me the same error when I have used this code! `Type 'Observable<CalendarEvent[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'CalendarEvent[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 24 more.`

Comment: because you were returning the obserable` return` this.getCalendarData().pipe(map((data: any). try removing that

Comment: Like this one? `return this.getCalendarData().subscribe((data: any) => {}`

Answer (score 0):

Use `from` operator to convert array to observable

```
return from(events);
```

Comment: Cannot find name 'from'. what is the code form importing

Comment: My method is already in `getCalendarEvents(): Observable<Array<CalendarEvent>>` where will I write the `return from(events);` In the service.ts?

Comment: yes. import the from operator. `import {from}   from 'rxjs'`

Comment: When I import the from, the entire method lines return error! `Type 'Observable<Observable<CalendarEvent>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<CalendarEvent[]>'.
  Type 'Observable<CalendarEvent>' is missing the following properties from type 'CalendarEvent[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 24 more.`